# How to get filename of newest file in directory?

Tags: file

Is there any way to get full filename of latest file (creation time or modification time) in directory?

filename.jpg

Comment: Welcome, clueless -- this is a reasonable question, but it is really about basic linux usage.  Things like that belong on our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), although I recommend you try and do a bit of research yourself first as you will be expected to demonstrate that you have tried.  When searching online for basic command line usage questions like this, **do not** include "raspberry pi" in your search terms, but **do** include linux.

Answer (score 3):

This ***might*** do what you want:

```
$ ls -t | head -n 1
```

If not, you might try [copying and pasting your question directly into your search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=How+to+get+filename+of+newest+file+in+directory%3F&atb=v278-1&ia=web). That's what I did to find this answer - it would work for you, too - even if you didn't know that `man ls` or `man find` might be useful commands.